# Convert reponse string to array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I got the string through auth API :

```
({
    "token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ...",
    "user":
     {
        "uid":"lda...",
        "sn":"Hugo",
        "mail":"abc@bla.com",
        "mobile":""
    }
})
```

I have tried `json_decode($ldapResponse)->user->uid`, but

> Error Trying to get property of non-object

appears. 
How can I convert this string to Array and get the value of `uid` in php?

Comment: Read [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$array= json_decode($your_json, TRUE);`
```